# Error: Expected Expression

Tags: c

I'm compiling my program and I'm getting the following two errors:

```
prog1.c:64:17: error: expected expression
    timeUpdate (struct dateAndTime orig);
                ^
prog1.c:67:20: error: expected expression
        dateUpdate(struct dateAndTime orig);
                   ^
```

I've read that such errors can be the result of details in the invisible space that are easy to miss, but I can't find any. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

struct time {
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct dateAndTime {
    struct date sdate;
    struct time stime;
};

struct time timeUpdate (struct time now) {
    now.seconds++;

    if (now.seconds == 60) { //next minute
        now.seconds = 0;
        now.minutes++;

        if (now.minutes == 60) { //next hour
            now.minutes = 0;
            now.hour++;

            if (now.hour == 24) //midnight
                now.hour = 0;
        }
    }

    return now;
}

struct date dateUpdate (struct date today) {
    struct date tomorrow;
    int numberOfDays (struct date d);

    if (today.day != numberOfDays (today)) {
        tomorrow.day = today.day + 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }
    else if (today.month == 12) { //end of year
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
    }
    else { //end of month
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }
    return tomorrow;
}

struct dateAndTime clockKeeper (struct dateAndTime orig) {

    timeUpdate (struct dateAndTime orig);

    if (orig.stime.hour == 0) {
        dateUpdate(struct dateAndTime orig);
    }

    return orig;
}

int main (void) {
    struct dateAndTime orig;

    printf ("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy)\n");
    scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &orig.sdate.month, &orig.sdate.day, &orig.sdate.year);

    printf ("Please enter a time (hh:mm:ss)\n");
    scanf ("%d:%d:%d", &orig.stime.hour, &orig.stime.minutes, &orig.stime.seconds);

    clockKeeper(orig);

    printf("%d/%d/%d @ %d:%d:%d\n", orig.sdate.month, orig.sdate.day, orig.sdate.year, orig.stime.hour, orig.stime.minutes, orig.stime.seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted:

```
timeUpdate (orig);
```

instead of:

```
timeUpdate (struct dateAndTime orig);
```

This is the same way you don't write `printf(const char* "Hello world!")` or `int x = 1; int y = 2; add(int x, int y)`.